# why is this CSS grid displaying in wrong dimensions in pixels?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am just starting out with CSS Grid and it's displaying proper boxes in proper places, but in wrong pixel size???? The main container is displaying at about `1500px` instead of `1200px` and all the row dimensions are wrong too.

```css
#container {
  width: 1200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 225px 175px 225px 160px;
}

.feature {
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.vertical {
  grid-row-end: span 2;
}

.im_picture {
  background-color: #336;
}

.im_picture img {}

.button {
  background-color: #808000;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="im_picture feature"></div>
  <div class="im_picture vertical"></div>
  <div class="im_picture"></div>
  <div class="im_picture vertical"></div>
  <div class="im_picture"></div>
  <div class="button">book a session</div>
```

Comment: The `#container` in your CodePen displays at exactly `1200px` for me, as expected. Specifically which boxes are displaying incorrectly for you, and what dimensions *should* they be displaying at?

Comment: Thank you. I need to check my browser settings, something is funny here. Chrome, zoom is at 100%; The container width is displaying at 1500px; rows are also all proportionally larger.

Comment: Working for me in both Chrome and Firefox. Statically 1200px. Check the compatibility as grid is not fully supported across the board yet: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with the code, it's an issue with a combination of Chrome and Windows settings

https://superuser.com/questions/1139259/how-to-adjust-ui-scaling-for-chrome